# check for a date in a particular format

Tags: java, date

How can i check that 
if a date is in a particular format like "dd/MM/yyyy" then it will do something
but if it is not in this format or if a string like "NA" is there or whatever is there it should throw an error.

Comment: use regular expressions. Check [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)

Comment: can u please elaborate it....
i m nt getting it  :)

Comment: If you are not able to create your own regualr expressions try [this](http://www.regexbuddy.com/library.html). In this it gives you a gui to give regular expression for various commonly used format like date etc.. you can validate your date using the generated regex and then parse the date using SimpleDateFormat as mentioned below.

Comment: @AurA: I think answer by Mr. juergen is simple and sober....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to parse the date with `SimpleDateFormat`. If it works the date is in the expected format.

Comment: :do you mean like this
     `try
     {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      sdf.parse(myDate.tostring());
     }
      catch(){}

     `

Comment: Actually i was also thinkin of that but was nt sure 
nw I am  :)
thanks